# Hylafax with serial over IP modem

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-vsphere, fax

I'm looking into virtualizing a Hylafax server which currently runs on a dedicated hardware running CentOS with a Divalogic card.

The main issue obviously is, how to connect the modem to the VM. There are serial over IP devices available at digi.com. Maybe there are others?

Regarding digi.com devices, as far as I understood one can install the RealPort software and then have a /dev/ttySx device presented to the Linux server. This device then can be used as serial connection to the modem.

Does someone have such a configuration in place? Or does someone have another idea to virtualize a Hylafax server (outbound faxes only).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

With [VSIfax](http://www.esker.com/solutions/fax_servers/solutions/fax_software_unix.asp) and VMWare, I've done a few things...

- I've used host-based serial passthrough to the server's physical port. This limited vMotion and the portability of the VM.
- I've tried PCI passthrough of a [Digi RAS](http://www.digi.com/products/serialcards/acceleportrasfamily#overview) card to a specific VM. This requires a RAM reservation and limits the portability of the virtual machine.
- I've used a Moxa IP-serial device for this purpose as well.

Comment: Using Hylafax is a requirement. I have a Moxa NP6650 in place but I'm wondering how to configure the port.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting you change, but describing my environments. I'd check with Moxa on the detail with VMWare. You shouldn't need to do anything at the hypervisor level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use a Moxa NPort 6650 Terminal Server, use the Real COM Linux driver and connect it to a serial port which is hooked up to a modem.